# Sending microphone input on laptop to Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspbian, pi-2

My Raspberry Pi 3 is connected to an access point and has a speaker connected to it. How can I send the microphone input from my laptop to the RPi and get it played through the speaker?

Comment: wouldn't a bluetooth speaker be easier?

Comment: Bluetooth will most probably only work when the rpi is nearby, wifi is stronger in this case.

Comment: TeamSpeak? You can adjust the quality of audio where skype or something may or may not give you good quality.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way would probably be to install Skype och Google Talk or something similar.

Comment: How exactly would this be done? Last I heard, neither are available on ARM, except through the web interfaces.